# Thymeleaf ${#request.requestURI} returns a double value

Tags: spring-boot, tomcat, thymeleaf, tomcat9

So I have this template in Thymeleaf:

```
<script th:src="@{|${#request.requestURI}ace-builds/src-noconflict/ace.js|}" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

What I want it to do is pull the current directory(?) it's in, and attach it to the front of the source. So if this is on the page `www.mywebsite.com/mypage`, it will generate the source tag `/mypage/ace-builds/src-noconflict/ace.js`.

From other posts here, it looks like that's what should happen, for me, I get this instead:
`/mypage/mypage/ace-builds/src-noconflict/ace.js`

I can't for the life of me figure out why this is happening. For those wondering why I'd want to do this in the first place, this program is running out of a WAR on a tomcat 9 server, and so the source tag needs to include the `mypage` war file name to pull from it, which I can hardcode to make work, and I can't pull static resources with just `/ace-builds/src-noconflict/ace.js`.

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, I am a fool and missed the advise in one of the threads I was checking. Just needed to use:

```
<script th:src="@{ace-builds/src-noconflict/ace.js}" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

I was trying regular src before, without thymeleaf, and thought the leading `/` was necessary. Not the case.